# I'm very new to C++ and I'm stuck trying to make a loop

Tags: c++

So i'm trying to write a code that has the user putting in a name of a character from a video game and then they receive information about said character, like a pokedex from pokemon. I am trying to make my code loop back and give the option of putting in another name, but I can't seem to figure out which loop to use or how to implement one.
Here is what I have so far. I want the code to ask if you want to research another villager. I did some research and thought maybe a dowhile loop would work but I dont know what I'm doing in that regard. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{  std::string villager, tammy, genji;
    std::cout << "Please enter a villager name.\n";
    std::cin >> villager;


    if (villager == "genji")
     {

        std::cout << "  \n";
        std::cout << "Genji\n";
        std::cout << "  \n";
        std::cout << "Rabbit\n";
        std::cout << "Male\n";
        std::cout << "Jock\n";
        std::cout << "  \n";
     }
    else if (villager == "tammy")
     {

        std::cout << "  \n";
        std::cout << "Tammy\n";
        std::cout << "  \n";
        std::cout << "Bear\n";
        std::cout << "Female\n";
        std::cout << "Jock\n";
        std::cout << "  \n"; 
     }
     std::cout << "Would you like to research another villager? Type yes or no.\n";
     std::cin >> answer;
```

sorry if my formatting is weird, I've never used this forum before.

Comment: You don't need the ```tammy``` and ```genji``` variables.

Answer (score 2):

A `do...while` loop will work perfectly well.
The format is `do {instructions} while (condition);`.
I would recommend having a nested loop to verify that the input is `yes` or `no`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string villager, answer;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter a villager name.\n";
        std::cin >> villager;

        if (villager == "genji")
        {
            std::cout << "\nGenji\n\n";
            std::cout << "Rabbit\n";
            std::cout << "Male\n";
            std::cout << "Jock\n\n";
        }
        else if (villager == "tammy")
        {
            std::cout << "\nTammy\n\n";
            std::cout << "Bear\n";
            std::cout << "Female\n";
            std::cout << "Jock\n\n";
        }

        do
        {
            std::cout << "Would you like to research another villager? Type yes or no.\n";
            std::cin >> answer;
        } while(answer.compare("yes") != 0 && answer.compare("no") != 0);

    } while(answer.compare("yes") == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `do-while` loop here:

```
int main()
{  
  std::string villager, tammy, genji, answer;

  do {

   // research villagers

   std::cout << "Would you like to research another villager? Type yes or no.\n";
   std::cin >> answer;
  } while (answer == "yes");
}
```

This will research a villager once, and then continue to do this as long as the user enters "yes" at the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

you can use while loop in your code.

```
bool isTrue = true;
while(isTrue){
 .........
.........
your code here inside
.........
.........
if(name="x")
    isTrue = false;
}
```

reference from https://meansflow.com/64/how-to-use-a-loop-back-in-c-to-make-the-program-infinite
You can see an example there

Answer (score 0):

A Do-While is the best solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{  std::string villager, tammy, genji,answer;
    do{
        std::cout << "Please enter a villager name.\n";
        std::cin >> villager;


        if (villager == "genji")
        {

           std::cout << "  \n";
           std::cout << "Genji\n";
           std::cout << "  \n";
           std::cout << "Rabbit\n";
           std::cout << "Male\n";
           std::cout << "Jock\n";
           std::cout << "  \n";
        }
        else if (villager == "tammy")
        {

           std::cout << "  \n";
           std::cout << "Tammy\n";
           std::cout << "  \n";
           std::cout << "Bear\n";
           std::cout << "Female\n";
           std::cout << "Jock\n";
           std::cout << "  \n"; 
        }
        std::cout << "Would you like to research another villager? Type yes or no.\n";
        std::cin >> answer;
   }while(answer == "yes");
```

The Do-While do execute the code at least one time, so you have the possibility to do an operation and the ask to the user what prefer.